# How to avoid the diuretic effect of caffeine or green tea?

Tags: caffeine, diuretics

I have been incorporating green tea into my diet for a long time because of all its benefits, but I discovered that I am very sensitive to the diuretic effect of caffeine, even to the small amount of caffeine in green tea. Over time (months) I thought I would become more tolerant but I am still sensitive. A single cup of tea is enough to make me urinate up to 4 times per hour during the next 4 hours after drinking a cup.

I really like all the benefits that green tea (and caffeine) gives me (physical performance,  metabolism boost, antioxidants ...) but it is becoming an annoyance for me to have to go to the bathroom so many times because of drinking this tea (and also be cautious of not being dehydrated), so here is my question:

Is it possible to eliminate or counteract the diuretic effect of caffeine, or at least mitigate it?

Comment: What has your research revealed? What makes you think caffeine is a diuretic?

Comment: Well, I guess I clicked the wrong vtc button, but it still works, I suppose

Comment: @DeNovo I find it curious that you would answer a question and vote to close it. What was  your close reason?

Comment: @CareyGregory I do that every once in a while. I meant to choose personal medical, since this is a particular case of "why am I urinating so much", which has a long differential.

Answer (score 2):

Caffeine intake is associated with increased urination, but controlled studies (e.g., [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/16167356) and [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/16167356)) demonstrate fairly rapid adaptation and no chronic diuretic effect.

For most people, if you want to take caffeine without experiencing the diuretic effect, you simply drink your caffeinated beverage regularly and wait for your nephron to move through the equilibration phase. One would expect some variation here, which is why I say for most people. There are, of course, other reasons for excessive urination (beyond caffeine consumption), which are best not addressed in this stack for reasons discussed [here](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/747/how-long-can-this-site-be-popular-if-everybody-is-asked-to-see-a-doctor/748#748). Since the OP states they have been drinking green tea for months and still experience a greater volume of urine output, I have both answered the general question about caffeine and voted to close the specific question (why am I urinating so much) as a personal medical question.

Comment: As I read it, I don't see they ask why they are urinating, just how to stop it. And they already indicated it has been months, which is long enough for adaptation to occur.

Comment: @JohnP Right. That's my point. This person should probably talk to their doctor. They are probably not urinating so much because of the caffeine

Comment: @JohnP to clarify, a medical question of: why is A causing B that has an answer, A doesn't cause B in your particular circumstance, and B is something that should be investigated, is a personal medical question (from my perspective). A patient who asked a physician "why is A causing B" would certainly require follow up questions about B, if A doesn't cause B, and B is associated with disease.